# Processing Set of Sets and return a flat Iterable

Tags: scala, functional-programming, yield, loops

```
val input=Set(Set("a","b"),Set("b","c"))
```

I want this:

```
Map("a"->1,"b"->2,"c"->1)
```

What is the best functional approach for implementing such functionality?
Using yield keyword results in nested Iterables:

```
output = for(firstlevel<-input) yield for(item<-firstlevel) yield item
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**update:** *incorporated the suggestion to use `input.toSeq.flatten`

instead of `input.toSeq flatMap { _.toSeq }`*

convert to a single sequence of values...

```
input.toSeq.flatten
```

...group values that match...

```
input.toSeq.flatten groupBy { identity }
```

...and count

```
input.toSeq.flatten groupBy { identity } mapValues { _.size }
```

Comment: why you do not use this syntax? input.toSeq.flatMap( _.toSeq ).groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)

Comment: Some of it is personal preference - such as where to place braces and tabs vs spaces - but I find that code written using infix notation is usually cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: p.s. I know you meant to write `input.toSeq.flatMap(_.toSeq ).groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)`.  That's wiki formatting for you.  I find it helps to wrap code in backticks when adding a comment on SO

Comment: It could be even simpler:`output ={input.toSeq flatten } groupBy { identity } mapValues { _.size }`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use for-comprehension and yield:

```
output = for{
    (set,idx) <- input.zipWithIndex
    item <- set
} yield (item -> idx)
```

The code in your last line can be simplified (but does not what you want):

```
output = for{
    set <- input
    item <- set
} yield item
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh boy, that's so ugly...

```
input.foldLeft(Map[String,Int]())((m,s) => 
   s.foldLeft(m)((n,t) => n + (t -> (1 + n.getOrElse(t,0)))))
```

**[Edit]**

The Collection-API needs really a method for "merging" two Maps (or did I just overlook it???), e.g.

```
def merge[A,B](m1: Map[A,B], m2:Map[A,B])(f: (B,B)=>B):Map[A,B] =
  m1.foldLeft(m2)((m,t) =>
      m + (t._1 -> m.get(t._1).map(k => f(k,t._2)).getOrElse(t._2)))
```

With this you could write something like:

```
input.map(_.map(x => x -> 1).toMap).reduceLeft(merge(_,_)(_+_))
```

**[Edit2]**

With Kevin's idea merge could be written as

```
def merge[A,B](m1: Map[A,B], m2:Map[A,B])(f: (B,B)=>B):Map[A,B] =
   m1.keys ++ m2.keys map {k => k ->
        List(m1.get(k), m2.get(k)).flatten.reduceLeft(f)} toMap
```

Seems like my Scala-Fu is still too weak. What's the best way to express

```
(o1,o2) match {
    case (Some(x),Some(y)) => Some(f(x,y))    
    case (Some(x), _) => Some(x)    
    case (_, Some(y)) => Some(y)    
    case => error("crack in the time-space-continuum")  
}
```

?

Comment: this make me to learn folding and curried functions, I think fold is good for many cases but in this case i prefered to use Kevin's solution because it is more declarative and more readable than fold method

Comment: Scala can already do the merge, but you have to explicitly use a `collection.immutable.Map` instead of a `collection.Map`.  You'd then write `val merged = m1 withDefault m2`, this relies of the fact that `Map[K,V]` extends `A=>B`

Comment: Actually, that still wont let you iterate over merged keys.  You'd need something more like `{val m1m2 = m1 withDefault m2; m1.keys++m2.keys map {k => k->m1m2(k)} toMap}`

Comment: @Kevin: I need a way to add the values together when a key is in both maps, so I don't see how a withDefault could help here.

Comment: @Landei: Ahh, I see, some sort of index-based zip perhaps, taking a `Map[K,V1]` a `Map[K,V2]` and returning a `Map[K,(Option[V1],Option[V2])]`

Comment: `m1.keys++m2.keys map {k => k -> (m1.get(k), m2.get(k))} toMap` would do it